# Call to undefined method Xoco70\Tournaments\TournamentsServiceProvider::loadRoutesFrom()

Tags: php, laravel

I just create my first plugin, now, I try to install it in a Laravel 5.3

After adding the Service provider to app.php, I get this message:

```
php artisan vendor:publish -- provider="Xoco70\Tournaments\TournamentsServiceProvider"


[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]                                        
Call to undefined method Xoco70\Tournaments\TournamentsServiceProvider::loadRoutesFrom()
```

My boot methode TournamentsServiceProvider:

```
public function boot()
    {
        $this->loadRoutesFrom(__DIR__.'/web.php');

        $viewPath = __DIR__.'/../resources/views';
        $this->loadViewsFrom($viewPath, 'tournaments');

        $this->loadMigrationsFrom(__DIR__.'/../database/migrations');
        $this->loadTranslationsFrom(__DIR__ . '/../translations', 'tournaments');

//        $this->publishes([__DIR__ . '/views' => base_path('resources/views/vendor/tournaments')]);
        $this->publishes([__DIR__ . '/../config/tournaments.php' => config_path('tournaments.php'),'tournaments']);
        $this->publishes([__DIR__ . '/../database/migrations' => $this->app->databasePath() . '/migrations'], 'tournaments');
        $this->publishes([__DIR__ . '/../database/seeds' => $this->app->databasePath() . '/seeds'], 'tournaments');
        $this->publishes([__DIR__ . '/../database/factories' => $this->app->databasePath() . '/factories'], 'tournaments');
        $this->publishes([__DIR__ . '/../resources/assets' => public_path('vendor/tournaments'),], 'tournaments');

    }
```

Any Idea why???

Comment: Does `TournamentsServiceProvider` extend `ServiceProvider`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up including routes in my ServiceProvider:

```
public function boot(Router $router)
{

    $viewPath = __DIR__ . '/../resources/views';
    $this->loadViewsFrom($viewPath, 'tournaments');

    $this->loadMigrationsFrom(__DIR__ . '/../database/migrations');
    $this->loadTranslationsFrom(__DIR__ . '/../translations', 'tournaments');

    $this->publishes([__DIR__ . '/../config/tournaments.php' => config_path('tournaments.php'), 'tournaments']);
    $this->publishes([__DIR__ . '/../database/migrations' => $this->app->databasePath() . '/migrations'], 'tournaments');
    $this->publishes([__DIR__ . '/../database/seeds' => $this->app->databasePath() . '/seeds'], 'tournaments');
    $this->publishes([__DIR__ . '/../database/factories' => $this->app->databasePath() . '/factories'], 'tournaments');
    $this->publishes([__DIR__ . '/../resources/assets' => public_path('vendor/tournaments'),], 'tournaments');

    $router->group(['prefix' => 'tournaments', 'middleware' => ['web']], function ($router) {
        $router->get('/', 'Xoco70\Tournaments\TreeController@index')->name('tree.index');
        $router->post('/championships/{championship}/trees', 'Xoco70\Tournaments\TreeController@store')->name('tree.index');
    });
}
```